# Azure Devops Sprint Burndown Configuration

Tags: azure, sprint, burndowncharts

Is there a way to configure the burndown chart in a way where I can change the Completed state to one of the middle states on my kanban board?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment and under development by the azure team in line with requests.

You can track the process at here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-burnupburndown-charts-to-include-resolved-wo/578309